# Open MIDI Bluetooth Configuration pane of MacOS programatically from Swift

Tags: swift, core-audio, core-bluetooth, midi, coremidi

I can open the `Audio MIDI Setup` app programatically like this:

```swift
NSWorkspace.shared.launchApplication("Audio MIDI Setup")
```

But how can I open the `Bluetooth Configuration` window inside the app?

[image: Bluetooth Configuration window]

I've seen other apps having a menu item which opens up this dialog directly.

Comment: do you have a (free) example app that presents the Bluetooth Configuration prompt?

Comment: This one: (menu item on the screenshot as well) https://apps.apple.com/hu/app/quickmidi/id1459790045

Comment: just added a bonus bit as well! if this solved the issue for you can you plz accept the answer 

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I was so excited of your answer I thought by awarding the bounty it gets accepted as well. Thank you very much! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple provides a window controller for developers to use called [`CABTLEMIDIWindowController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreaudiokit/cabtlemidiwindowcontroller). The documentation is pretty sparse, but there is a bit more information in the code comments:

```
/**
@class CABTLEMIDIWindowController

@abstract  A window controller object that can present a window that displays nearby
 Bluetooth-based MIDI peripherals. The user can select one of those peripherals and 
 pair it with their mac. Additionally, the user can advertise the mac as a 
 Bluetooth-based MIDI peripheral.
 
@discussion To use this class, create an instance of the CABTLEMIDIWindowController,
 initialize it, and call showWindow: to display the UI.
*/
```

Usage is surprisingly straightforward:

```
let windowController = CABTLEMIDIWindowController()
windowController.showWindow(self)
```

**NOTE:**

Your app must have bluetooth configured and approved otherwise the window controller will appear like this:

[image: Error]

You must select Bluetooth from the App Sandbox settings and add the `NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription` key to your Info.plist:

[image: setup]

**FULL EXAMPLE:**

```
import Cocoa
import CoreBluetooth
import CoreAudioKit

class ViewController: NSViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    fileprivate var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }
    
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if (central.state == .poweredOn) {
            let windowController = CABTLEMIDIWindowController()
            windowController.showWindow(self)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Success]

**BONUS:**

Found this while snooping around. Saves users a lot of clicks by opening System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Bluetooth:

```
NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(string: "x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Bluetooth")!)
```